# How can i force a complete refresh (re downloading cached files) after each publish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, webpack, publish

I have a website built using `ReactJS` which is being continuously developed and i publish a new version and build almost every day, the people who use my website have this problem that even if they do a `F5` and refresh the page, everything is `Memory Cached` for example the `chunk` files, which means they don't get the latest changes and they have to manually clear the browser cache to get some result!
So here is my question, how can i tell my app that "hey, this is a new build", so if a refresh `F5` happens, it downloads everything and doesn't use the cached files
Any solution is much appreciated
Thanks.

**Update 01:** 
I just tried changing my `jsconfig.json` file, in hopes of changing the chunk name something like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "output": {        
        "chunkFilename": "[name].chunkv2.0.js"
    }       
}
```

But none of the chunks were different, meaning their name was a still `[somehash].chunk.js`
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The way I've always done to work around this is to use a query string corresponding to the version number or release date/time. This is then appended to the URLs of the requested resources and because the query string changes it's a different URL as far as the browser's caching behaviour is concerned.

Comment: Following, experiencing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to improve your build pipeline and ensure you are busting the browsers cache. Read [Strategies for Cache-Busting](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/), although this is aimed at CSS the principles apply for JavaScript too.

If you're using Webpack then checkout it's own [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) on the topic.

Comment: Is it possible to add a version name to all the chunks that get build with webpack, i mena something like this:  `main.bad98a53.chunk.js` should be `main.bad98a53.chunk_v0.1.js`

Comment: @AliAhmadi Webpack is essentially just JavaScript so you can do what you like. You'll just need to implement it. The answer is yes, you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I tell my app that "hey, this is a new build"? so if a refresh F5 happens, it downloads everything and doesn't use the cached files

sure, you can

> in hopes of changing the chunk name something like this `main.bad98a53.chunk_v0.1.j`

no need

### How can you notify the changes to the website?

first, you should use `[contenthash]` fo chunk name in webpack, and when you publish a new version, the `contenthash` would change if the content of the chunk changed.

second, use the fetch to get the HTML text content which contains scripts and compare it with the previous one like string. The text would like this

```
"
<html>
  //...
  <script src="main.11bsfas21.js"></script>
</html>
"

// after publish
"
<html>
  //...
  <script src="main.aagssh.js"></script>
</html>
"
```

if it has a difference, execute `location.reload(true)`

the code would like this

```js
let previous;
let htmlContent;

const diff = (callback) => {
  if (!previous) {
    previous = htmlContent;
    return
  }
  if (previous === htmlContent) return

  callback()
}

const loadContent = async () => {
  // get the html content
  const content = await window.fetch(location.host).then(res => res.text())
  return content
}

setTimeout(() => {
  loadContent()
     .then(content => {
       htmlContent = content;
       diff(() => location.reload(true))
     })
}, 1000)
```

this just an example, you can custom the callback like show a Model component.
The main work compares the text of HTML, if the `contenthash` changes, the text of HTML wouldn't equal and invoke callback.

use `location.reload(true)`, which would force the website to use the lastest source rather than use cache resources.